# VBA Yahoo Login

Tags: vba, excel, yahoo

I'm trying to make a macro on VBA to login to yahoo.
But I'm having trouble too submit the password part, since the username / password are on different pages.

I keep receiving the error

> Run Time Error '424' object required

on the `.Document.getElementById("login-passwd").Value` line.

```
    Sub WebLogin()
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "https://login.yahoo.com/"
    Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
    .Document.getElementById("login-username").Value = "username"
    .Document.getElementById("login-signin").Click
    Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    .Document.getElementById("login-passwd").Value = "password*"
    .Document.getElementById("login-signin").Click
End With

End Sub
```

I imagine that the HTML element are not beeing found, but I already tried adding a delay, another code's for waiting the page to load and nothing seens to work.

Here are the specfic HTML code for both fields.

```
<input name="username" tabindex="1" class="phone-no " id="login-username" autofocus="true" type="text" placeholder="Insira seu e-mail" value="" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none">
<input type="password" id="login-passwd" name="password" placeholder="Senha" autofocus="">
```

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

Run Time Error '424' is raised because `IE.Document.getElementById("login-passwd")` does not exist, and you attempt to access its `.Value`

Error handling in `VBA` is done with labels, and can get pretty ugly pretty quick.

You need to define a label, and an `On Error` statement

Let's define this subroutine:

```
Sub WaitAndFeed(ByRef IE, ByVal field As String, ByVal value As String)
    On Error GoTo NoObjErr
    While Not (IE.Document.getElementById(field) Is Nothing)
    NoObjErr:
        DoEvents
        IE.Document.getElementById(field).Value = value
        IE.Document.getElementById("login-signin").Click
    Wend
End Sub
```

Your code should now be modified to:

```
Sub WebLogin()
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "https://login.yahoo.com/"
        Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With
    Call WaitAndFeed(IE, "login-username", "username")
    Call WaitAndFeed(IE, "login-passwd", "password")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. I'm learning VBA on the fly, still on basics. I tried your code, and it throws the very same error, and do exactly the same thing then before. That beeing, fill the username, submit, and crashes before filling the password.

Comment: I guess it's missing a wait until ready, after submiting the username, right? Since both fields are in different pages. But I tried that, and didn't work too.

Comment: Also the correct is "login-passwd" right? But also tried that with success.

Comment: fixed it, you can give it a try now

Comment: Now it doesn't even fill the username, and raise the error on the same line (IE.Document.getElementById(field).value = value).